# what will be the alternate word for convey in the following sentence

Tags: word-usage

I am writing my first official email in English which happens to be my second language.
I am unsure about the correctness of the following sentence. Please help.

**The detected error is false positive, and I have verified this against the source. I believe you have updated your system to check against improper pricing, but the same was never conveyed to us.**

explain--> The situation is that we send our stock related information to another site for selling. the format of data that we send was agreed between us. Now suddenly they had changed the system without telling us hence the error came.

Comment: Try *communicated.*

Comment: @Jim post that as an answer.

Comment: Ratna, the title can have the word *alternative* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/alternative_1?q=alternative and http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/alternative_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one notable error in your sentence:

> The detected error is **a** false positive, and I have verified this against the source. I believe you have updated your system to check against improper pricing, but the same was never conveyed to us.